# successful server response without executing the Ajax route in NodeJs / Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I register my login route

```
app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
```

and this module contains the route to render my login HTML page and the Ajax call validating the login.

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) { // render login HTML page
        res.render('login');
});

router.post('/validateLogin', function (req, res) { // Ajax call - login button pressed
        var data = req.body;
        var username = data.username;
        var password = data.password;

        var loginIsValid = true; // TEST

        var session = req.session;
        session.user = { // TEST
          userId: 0 // TEST
        };

        res.send({
            isValid: loginIsValid
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The client has a login button. This button executes an Ajax call to the server. If the login is valid the user should get redirected to another page.

```
function login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validateLogin', // Ajax route name
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: $("#edtLoginUsername").val(),
            password: $("#edtLoginPassword").val()
        })
    }).done(function (response) { // server response
        if (response.isValid) { // valid login?
            // redirect the user to another page
        } else {
            alert("invalid login");
        }
    }).fail(function () {

    });
}
```

The code always results in "invalid login". I started debugging `response`. This variable returns my full HTML as a string. It's not the correct response object from the server.

I created a `console.log` in my Ajax route and this route never gets called.

The client does not throw the "not found" error and gets a successful response even when not calling the route on the server?

As I said the `response` is not correct, it just contains my full HTML page as a string.

---

**Edit**

The response object contains

```
"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title> </head>

<link href="/style/base.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="/style/header.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="/style/button.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="/style/input.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="/style/link.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>


<link href="/style/templates/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/client/templates/login.js"></script>

<div id="pageContent">
    <div id="loginContainer">
        <img id="logo" src="/resources/logo/img_logo_big.png">

        <div id="frmLogin">
          <div id="frmLoginHeader">
            <p id="loginHeaderTitle">Login</p>
          </div>

          User
          <input class="edt" id="edtLoginUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username">

          Password
          <input class="edt" id="edtLoginPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

          <button class="btn" id="btnLogin">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div> </div>


</body> </html> "
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `response` object?

Comment: can you attach response object too?

Comment: I updated my answer, this content is one single string

Comment: can you just check once whether you are reaching to correct url , if yes what response is coming?

Answer (score 0):

you create a route prefix to login all your routes now are under "/login"

so you can change your ajax url to

```js
url: 'login/validateLogin', // Ajax route name
```

or you can change you prefix

```js
app.use('/', require('./routes/login'));
```

and to get  the login page do

```js
router.get('/login', function (req, res) { // render login HTML page
        res.render('login');
});
```

Comment: first I changed my Ajax url to `'login/validateLogin'` and `'/login/validateLogin'` that did not work. After that I changed my `router.js` to your second suggestion

Comment: you dont need "/login/validateLogin" in the server for the first option you need only the change the ajax url